# Remove some array elements before making a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

The following code gets me all products when the values of `$arr` are not set as `NULL`.

`$arr` sometimes also includes values which need to be filtered out.

That means, with `$condition` I would like to check if "all" values from the array `$arr` are not set as `NULL` BUT ignore the values "apple", "orange" and "banana" when you found them in the array.

Is there a way to reach my goal? I also tried to remove those elements from the array (line 2) but for some reason that is not working for me.

```
$arr = $_POST['selected_checkboxes'];
unset($arr["apple"], $arr["orange"], $arr["banana"]); // Trying to remove these keys from the array
var_dump($arr);
$products = array();
$condition = '`' . join('` IS NOT NULL AND `', $arr) . '` IS NOT NULL';
if($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM produkte WHERE $condition")){
    while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        if (!in_array($row->name, $products)) {
            array_push( $products, array('name'=>$row->name, 'image'=>$row->image, 'link'=>$row->link) );
        }
    }
}
else {
    array_push($products, 'error');
}
```

Comment: You could probably do an array_walk on the post array and filter that way.

Comment: Is your product table called "product" or "produkte" if the code above was copied and pasted this may be your problem. In either case can you elaborate on what is not working please? Does your product array have "error" in it?

Comment: Please show the output of `var_dump($arr);` - unsetting the array elements should work

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code provided, I am guessing that you have confusion between keys and values; `$arr['apples']` would only exist if you had a checkbox `<input ... name="apples">`, but based on your SQL it appears that you have `<input ... name="selected_checkboxes" value="apples">`; in which case, you might want to try something like:

```
<?php
    $filter = ['banana', 'orange', 'apple'];
    $p = ['papaya', 'mango', 'pear', 'apple', 'grape', 'orange', 'cranberry'];
    $arr = array_filter($p, function($v) use($filter) { return !in_array($v, $filter); });
    var_dump($arr);
```